# transactionscope locks the tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

in my app, transaction scope is there, inside that i'm doing all copying operation to dc object and finnally dc.submittchanges() will be performed.

Will the transaction scope locks down the table present in dc?, will this cause any deadlocks?

Eg:

```
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
            {
                using (var dc = new ProposalDataContext(_ConnectionString))
                {
    scope.Complete(); 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

`TransactionScope` makes the code block transactional.  While the code has not been `COMMITED` the tables involved will be locked, if another process requests the contents of the table(s) involved it will have to wait until the transaction is committed or rolled back.

Comment: when scope.complete() is called, then only tables will be committed?. till that time whatever the table loaded with DataLoadOptions will be locked out correct?

Comment: Also one more thing, when we load table using DataLoadOptions, will it copy the tables to c# memory?, if so why another transaction has to wait for completion of scope?, everything will be in c# memory right

Comment: @LLL - when scope.Complete() is called it indicates that the operations inside the block are completed and that the transaction is ready to be committed. Until that time the tables will be locked, yes.

Comment: @LLL - since you are specifying a `using` statement the object will perform a memory cleanup after it has committed the transaction.  This is up to the CLR when the garbage collector kicks in but the objects being used within the transaction will be freed up by the CLR.

Comment: Ok, one more thing, what if there are 10 users, how does it behaves in this scenario?

Comment: @LLL - first come, first served.  The other users will have to wait until the transaction is completed/comitted/rolled back.  Unless the isolation level on the database is changed (not recommended).  This is default behavior to ensure no dirty reads are performed. As long as the transaction is not long running this will be fine.

Comment: So according to you, if my app is shared with 100 users, then if 100 users press save at a time, then if 1st user gets chance 1st & 100th users as last then 100th user has to wait till the completion of transaction?, also he should get time out if there is any specific timeout?

Comment: @LLL - yes. If your transaction takes `100ms` to complete then there will be no issue here and it will be transparent to the user.

Comment: Hi, for a transaction scope, only the corresponding rows in a table will be locked or the whole table gets locked? This lock will get released after submit changes or after scope is completed?

Comment: @LLL - the whole table. After submit changes / scope is completed is the same thing.  It's a transaction and it follows the rules of `ACID`.  Everything commits as a whole.

Comment: How we can unlock the table while transaction? Is there anything that provide by TransactionScope to us to unlock table or sort of such thing.